# Не работает база данных после установки на Debian

Tags: mysql, debian

Установил БД на Debian, пытаюсь к ней подключиться командой `mysql`

И мне в ответ:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

По умолчанию у рута либо должен стоять пароль "root", либо пароля не должно быть вообще. А ни одно, ни другое не работает.

Что делать?

Comment: А там не было старой базы, которую подхватила новая установка?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Нет, до этого база данных вообще на сервере не стояла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще должны были спросить ещё при установке, но если нет, то:

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure --force mysql-server-5.5`

Если я ничего не напутал, эта команда должна выдать окошко, в котором предложит установить новый пароль для root'a. (Напомню, что рут MySQL не имеет к системному руту никакого отношения, и пароль у него отдельный.)

Answer (score 1):

Инструкция по замене пароля:

1. Остановить mysql
2. Создать текстовый файл, содержащий 1 строку с запросом на смену пароля

Для MySQL 5.7.6 и выше:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

Для MySQL 5.7.5 и ниже:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

3. Запустить сервер из командной строки

   shell> mysqld_safe --init-file=/МойФайлСоСбросомПароля &
4. Остановить сервер
5. Запустить сервер обычным образом

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql -u root -p
```

и введите свой пароль от Root (суперпользователь mysql`a, не debian)

Comment: Я так уже пробовал. По умолчанию у рута либо должен стоять пароль "root", либо пароля не должно быть вообще. А ни одно, ни другое не работает.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin по умолчанию новый пароль предлагают задать ещё при установке. Почему вам не предложили — загадка.)